# Android NDK and Libraries Layer

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am confused about the Android NDK and Libraries layer of Android architecture. What I mean, at the Libraries layer you get .so files either C or C++. When we write an application in Android using java and do part of the development in NDK, where dose the NDK part fit? Dose it reside in the Applications layer or can we say it's part of the Libraries layer?

I have this dilemma as the final out put of the NDK is a .so which we load in to the java application as a library. I am writing a report for an application we have developed and wondering where to put the NDK part from these layers.

[image]

Comment: your question is a little bit unclear, you are talking about your apk package, the runtime environment, the design of this OS, ... ? that picture is just a list of components, says nothing about the Android internals, you can only get confused if you are looking at that picture trying to understand what the NDK is about.

Comment: Everything you pack into your application is application layer.

Comment: Yes, am talking about the apk. The NDK application is included in it. So it looks like the NDK part belongs to the application layer? @user1797612 no I was not trying to understand what NDK using that diagram. For the documentation work wondering whether to discuss the NDK part as in libraries

Comment: layer. Ultimately the NDK part is a dynamic library. However it looks like you can only add or remove libraries from this layer only by re-flashing the whole Android platform..right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you mean but I will try to compose an answer.

With the NDK you get everything for coding from really low-level stuff like kernel headers and assembly to really high level calls like the ones about the activity life cycle.

Using your words and taking this picture as reference with the NDK you can go from the bottom up and viceversa, you can use all the layers with the NDK.

But this is the theory, for example you can even code a linux kernel module ( a driver ) with the NDK, but in practice you probably can't do this because all the commercial phones use a monolithic kernel, so if your application needs a driver to work you have to trash your idea because of real-world-scenario limits .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually we have implemented a kernel driver (not in NDK) though. We are communicating with the kernel driver from the application layer and in doing so uses a NDK part. This maps the java to C and calls the module. This NDK part I am wondering which layer would it fit. The applications or the library?